# Redirection loop with NGinx on a rails application with ssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx

I know there is a lot of question on a similar problem but I can find the solution for my case. I have this nginx configuration :

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.lescollectionneurs.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/lescollectionneurs/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}

server {
  listen 443 default ssl;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/lescollectionneurs/current/public;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/myssl.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/myssl.key;

  ssl_session_timeout 5m;

  ssl_protocols sslv3 tlsv1 tlsv1.1 tlsv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

In my rails application, I have `config.force_ssl = true`. When I log at the nginx's logs, I have a redirection loop and it fail in the browser. There is nothing in my production logs.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was only to add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` in the `location` block in the ssl part.